# Python add noise to image breaks PNG

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, signal-processing

I'm trying to create a image system in Python 3 to be used in a web app. The idea is to load an image from disk and add some random noise to it. When I try this, I get what looks like a totally random image, not resembling the original:

[image: test1] [image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import random_noise
from random import randint
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
import io


image_files = [
    {
        'name': 'test1',
        'file': 'test1.png'
    },
    {
        'name': 'test2',
        'file': 'test2.png'
    }
]


def gen_image():
    rand_image = randint(0, len(image_files)-1)
    image_file = image_files[rand_image]['file']
    image_name = image_files[rand_image]['name']
    image_path = str(Path().absolute())+'/img/'+image_file
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    noise_img = random_noise(img, mode='s&p', amount=0.1)
    img = Image.fromarray(noise_img, 'RGB')

    fp = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(fp, format="PNG")
    content = fp.getvalue()
    return content


gen_image()
```

I have also tried using pypng:

```
import png

# Added the following to gen_image()
content = png.from_array(noise_img, mode='L;1')
content.save('image.png')
```

How can I load a png (With alpha transparency) from disk, add some noise to it, and return it so that it can be displayed by web server code (flask, aiohttp, etc).

As indicated in the answer by makayla, this makes it better: `noise_img = (noise_img*255).astype(np.uint8)` but the colors are still wrong and there's no transparency.

Here's the updated function for that:

```
def gen_image():
    rand_image = randint(0, len(image_files)-1)
    image_file = image_files[rand_image]['file']
    image_name = image_files[rand_image]['name']
    image_path = str(Path().absolute())+'/img/'+image_file
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

    cv2.imshow('dst_rt', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Problem exists somewhere below this line.
    img = random_noise(img, mode='s&p', amount=0.1)
    img = (img*255).astype(np.uint8)
    img =  Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB')

    fp = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(fp, format="png")
    content = fp.getvalue()

    return content
```

This will popup a pre-noise image and return the noised image. RGB (And alpha) problem exists in returned image.

I think the problem is it needs to be `RGBA` but when I change to that, I get `ValueError: buffer is not large enough`

Comment: I don't see anything that tries to add the noise to the original image.

Comment: `noise_img = random_noise(img, mode='s&p', amount=0.1)`

Comment: updated question with function and comment.

Comment: need RGBA but shape is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given all the new information I am updating my answer with a few more tips for debugging the issue.

I found a [site here](http://png-pixel.com/) which creates sample transparent images. I created a 64x64 cyan (R=0, G=255, B=255) image with a transparency layer of 0.5. I used this to test your code.

[image: cyan image]

I read in the image two ways to compare: `im1 = cv2.imread(fileName)` and `im2 = cv2.imread(fileName,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`. `np.shape(im1)` returned `(64,64,3)` and `np.shape(im2)` returned `(64,64,4)`. This is why that flag is required--the default imread settings in opencv will read in a transparent image as a normal RGB image.

However opencv reads in as BGR instead of RGB, and since you cannot save out with opencv, you'll need to convert it to the correct order otherwise the image will have reversed color. For example, my cyan image, when viewed with the reversed color appears like this:

[image: cyan reversed (yellow)]

You can change this using openCV's [color conversion function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) like this `im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)` ([Here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0) is a list of all the color conversion codes). Again, double check the size of your image if you need to, it should still have four channels since you converted it to RGBA.

You can now add your noise to your image. **Just so you know, this is also going to add noise to your alpha channel as well, randomly making some pixels more transparent and others less transparent.** The [random_noise function](https://kite.com/python/docs/skimage.util.random_noise) from skimage converts your image to float and returns it as float. This means the image values, normally integers ranging from 0 to 255, are converted to decimal values from 0 to 1. Your line `img = Image.fromarray(noise_img, 'RGB')` does not know what to do with the floating point noise_img. That's why the image is all messed up when you save it, as well as when I tried to show it.

So I took my cyan image, added noise, and then converted the floats back to 8 bits.

```
noise_img = random_noise(im, mode='s&p', amount=0.1)
noise_img = (noise_img*255).astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(noise_img, 'RGBA')
```

It now looks like this (screenshot) using `img.show()`:

[image: s&p cyan image]

I used the PIL library to save out my image instead of openCV so it's as close to your code as possible.

```
fp = 'saved_im.png'
img.save(fp, format="png")
```

I loaded the image into powerpoint to double-check that it preserved the transparency when I saved it using this method. Here is a screenshot of the saved image overlaid on a red circle in powerpoint:

[image: transparent overlay]

Comment: Thanks. That makes it better but there's still some problem. This can easily be seen if I set the noise `amount` to `0.0`. Please see updated question.

Comment: I think the problem is it needs to be `RGBA` but when I change to that, I get `ValueError: buffer is not large enough`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your last few lines are trying to do, especially the ```io.BytesIO()``` but it looks like you're just trying to save your image. I would recommend just using [openCV's function imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite). if you read this you'll see it specifically supports saving png files with alpha channels.

Comment: I also just tested your code with an RGBA image. I don't think your ```imread``` call is reading in an RGBA image. Try calling ```img = cv2.imread(captcha_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)``` instead. Also I can see your colors are reversed in your output image. This is because openCV is using BGR format instead of RGB. If you read an image with openCV (which will be in BGR) then try to save it with another function, which most likely writes in RGB format, your colors will be reversed. Again why I recommend using openCV imwrite, since you're already using openCV's imread.

Comment: btw, an easy way to test if you are reading in your image with an alpha channel is to check the shape of your image. ```print(np.shape(img))``` . If your image is (rows, columns, **3**), you have 3 channels, (R, G, and B) meaning no transparency. If your image is (rows, columns, **4**), you have 4 channels, (R, G, B, and A) so you've probably read it in correctly.

Comment: If I use `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` I get images like: http://i.imgur.com/QP1Zr4l.png . How can I return the bytes using openCV so my web server can serve the image raw (Not by filesystem)? `imwrite()` saves a file to the filesystem, which is not an option. After converting to numpy array, the shape shows as `(64, 64, 5)`. I will be adding a bounty to this question.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure I can help you with the web server portion. But this is strange that your image has 5 channels...I'm not sure what this means. In my experience transparent images have 4 channels, R,G,B (colors) and A, the alpha channel which dictates the amount of transparency for each pixel. If you can upload your original image maybe I can look at it, since it appears the images you've uploaded are screenshots? I find it's easier to debug your code with simpler test images to really pinpoint what's going on. I'll update my answer with some sample code.

Comment: That did it. Thank you